# JavaScript SVG World Map library that works offline?

Tags: javascript, svg, gis, geojson

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that allows me to build SVG maps from locally hosted shape data (to allow users to use the application without internet connection).

1) Where should I be looking?
2) Is GeoJson a good candidate for shape data?
3) Where do I find shape data for country borders and (1-level deep) subnational entities?

*If the library also supported drawing circles with the center point at specific lat/long coordinates, that would be a bonus :)*

Answer (score 5):

You could try to use [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/) for that. It has a converter to generate custom maps.

Comment: @BjornTipling Thank you, I'm a developer of jVectorMap. Any questions or suggestions are welcome on GitHub (https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap)

Answer (score 0):

Raphaeljs should meet all your requirements. There is an actual example of a map right here http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html. Of course you'll need to provide the appropriate data.